# Get the changed value between two columns of table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have one table like below format:

```
ID            Date                  Frequency
1            01/06/2009               1
2            01/06/2009               1
3            01/06/2009               2
4            01/06/2009               1      *
5            01/06/2009               1
6            01/06/2009               2      *
```

I want result set like below:

```
Current   : 6            01/06/2009               2      
Previous  : 4            01/06/2009               1
```

I am using SQL Server 2000 databse.Please provide solution for above resultset.

Comment: Please explain the reasoning behind the required output - it's not at all clear how this is to be arrived at - nor what the asterisks mean in the table data.

Comment: What is this current, previous? Are you trying to build string? What logic should we use?

Answer (score 0):

This is a pretty basic SQL statement

```
SELECT count(ID), date, Frequency
FROM yourTable
Group By Date, Frequency
ORDER BY Frequency DESC
```

But I'm not positve due to * and the current: Previous: statements